# Find row where two columns are close to optimal values

Tags: r

let´s say I have a data.frame like this:

```
x = data.frame(slope = seq(0.9, -0.75, length.out = 13), 
               n_neg = c(161,48,15,6,3,3,1,1,1,0,0,0,0))
```

I want to find the row where slope is closest to zero and the number of negative observations n_neg is also closest to zero. In this case it would be row number 8. `n_neg` can also be zero but slope is more important.

I already tried `which.min(abs(x$slope - 0) & abs(x$n_neg -0))` but this gives me the row with the first zero in `n_neg` (in this case row number 10).

Thanks for your help,

Comment: `which.min(abs(x$slope))` gives you 8.

Comment: Thanks, in this case it is true, sorry, bad example. Let´s take this one: x = data.frame(slope = seq(0.9, -0.75, length.out = 13), n_neg = c(161,48,15,6,3,3,3,3,1,1,0,0,0)). If I use which.min(abs(x$slope)), it will give me 8, however I want to have the row where slope is closest to 0 AND n_neg is closest to zero as well. in this example it would be row number 9. So I would need something close to zero but with a tolerance I can specify, in this case 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to find the best penalty to compute a score in your situation. You can look for the best a and b parameter as bellow :

```r
x <- data.frame(slope = seq(0.9, -0.75, length.out = 13), 
               n_neg = c(161,48,15,6,3,3,1,1,1,0,0,0,0))

penalty <- function(x, y, a, b){a*abs(x) + b*abs(y)}

x$score <- penalty(x = x$slope, y = x$n_neg, a = 1/max(x$slope), b = 1/max(x$n_neg))
min(x$score)
#> [1] 0.07565562
which.min(x$score)
#> [1] 8
x
#>      slope n_neg      score
#> 1   0.9000   161 2.00000000
#> 2   0.7625    48 1.14535887
#> 3   0.6250    15 0.78761215
#> 4   0.4875     6 0.57893375
#> 5   0.3500     3 0.40752243
#> 6   0.2125     3 0.25474465
#> 7   0.0750     1 0.08954451
#> 8  -0.0625     1 0.07565562
#> 9  -0.2000     1 0.22843340
#> 10 -0.3375     0 0.37500000
#> 11 -0.4750     0 0.52777778
#> 12 -0.6125     0 0.68055556
#> 13 -0.7500     0 0.83333333
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like `x[head(order(abs(x$slope),x$n_neg),1),]`? In this case, the `slope` is prioritized to `n_neg` to seek the minimum.

The result thus gives:

```
> x[head(order(abs(x$slope),x$n_neg),1),]
    slope n_neg
8 -0.0625     1
```